# Does Pardot respect the Salesforce Role Hierarchy?

Tags: sharing, role-hierarchy, pardot

We have a strict sharing model in Salesforce whereby EMEA can't see APAC data and vice-versa.  We've achieved this through the Salesforce Role Hierarchy.  Is this preserved in Pardot too, i.e., if a user is in the EMEA role on Salesforce, will they be prevented from seeing APAC data in Pardot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no sharing model in Pardot like there is in Salesforce. The only way to differentiate prospects in Pardot based on sharing in Salesforce, is to tie multiple Pardot accounts to one Salesforce Org. This comes with a price of course, since you need more Pardot licences, but it works because you can then share particular data in Salesforce with different connector users.

[more information here on tying multiple Pardot accounts to Salesforce](http://help.pardot.com/customer/portal/articles/2128046-can-i-tie-multiple-pardot-and-salesforce-accounts-together-).

Answer (score 0):

No Pardot won't respect your EMEA/APAC roles from Salesforce. The trick is to understand the PARDOT roles. There are 4 standard roles:

Sales - can only see Prospects assigned to them
Sales Manager - can see ALL prospects (even those not assigned to them) and some reporting.
Marketing - can see all prospects and perform marketing function (send list emails, segment lists, etc.)
Admin - can do everything, including account upgrades.

This is the limit of prospect visibility restrictions - either Sales role and see only prospects assigned to them (assigned in Salesforce) or Sales Manager and see all prospects.

It sounds like you want to assign all your people the role of 'Sales' and then call it a day. Maybe give your VPs the view of 'Sales Manager' but that's about it.